# Error when selecting iron-list item manually

Tags: javascript, polymer

- polymer 1.4.0
- iron-list 1.3.1

I am manually triggering selection of an item when a certain element is clicked. This works fine as long as I have `selection-enabled multi-selection` attributes on my iron-list. However, I would like to remove them because the associated event handlers (select on tap) interfere with mine. When I do I get `polymer.html:3942 Uncaught TypeError: userArray.slice is not a function`

Some loggging shows that `_itemsChanged` is doing
`Polymer.Collection.get(this.items)` which expects an array of all items further down the chain, but is getting just the selected item as an object. So I've found the problem, but I don't know why it's happening or how to fix it.

It looks in the code like `selection-enabled` is just adding the handlers. Is that a wrong assumption? Is it always needed to do selections? Is there something wrong with my function perhaps?

This is my select function, adapted from the `_selectItem` function in [this post's](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/100#issuecomment-141422735) jsbin :

```
toggleSelect: function(e) {
  this.$.itemsList.toggleSelectionForItem(e.model.item);
},
```

My apologies as this question is a bit rushed. I will try to provide a fiddle later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The code in the original post is correct, the solution is to use `multi-selection` but not `selection-enabled`.

## Explanation

Since `toggleSelectionForItem` appears to depend on `multi-selection` and it is `selection-enabled` that fires the unwanted select we can simply remove `selection-enabled` to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

try changing selectedItem property instead of calling the method toggleSelectionForItem. From the description of this method it seems that it is more related to multi select property.

Comment: This turned out to be unnecessary, but pointing out that `toggleSelectionForItem` needs `multi-selection` was the key. Thanks so much!